# Powershell Array to string with specific formatting

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

Suppose I have an array with random values in it, like for instance

```
$a=@(0..5)
```

and I would like to format that array in a string like this :

```
{0,1,2,3,4}
```

comma separated values between curly braces. The "catch" is that I don't know in advance the size of the array, and in some cases, when there's only one record the type won't be array but psobject, when it's a unique PSObject I don't need curly braces and commas, I want to leave it as it is.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything for this?

Comment: For the array case, it's pretty simple.  `"{$($a -join ',')}"`  I'm not sure I understand the "in some cases" clause.  Can you elaborate on your PSObjects?  You probably want to switch on `if ($a -is [PSObject])`

Comment: `'{{{0}}}' -f ($a -join ',')`

Comment: There's also the Perl-ish way: `$ofs=','; "{$a}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for this (`if` statement on the input object type, and use of @beatcracker's method) :

**Code :**

```
//insert an array and a custom object in an input array
$input = @(@(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
           [PSCustomObject]@{ title = "My"; first = "Custom"; last = "Object" })

//an empty output array
$output = @()

//foreach item in the input array
foreach($item in $input) {

    //if item base type is array
    if($item.GetType().BaseType.Name -eq "Array") {

        //process and add to output array
        $output += "{{{0}}}" -f ($item -join ",")
    } else {

        //add to output array as-is
        $output += $item
    }
}

//echo output array
$output
```

**Output :**

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5}

title first  last  
----- -----  ----  
My    Custom Object
```

Info : `{0}` is a placeholder for the 1st value after `-f`, `($item -join ",")` ; the next one would have been `{1}` ([more info here](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)).

Additional curly brackets are there to escape surrounding curly brackets to make sure they appear in the final string.

Comment: Your answer looks great! :) Would you mind explaining what "{{{0}}}" stands for? Thanks again!